# Retrieve files from google drive folder based on search term

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am quite new to working in google drive and  I am well aware that i can't ask stackoverflow the complete example of the below scenario, however if you can direct me to something similar it would be really helpful. I am quite stuck and couldn't move forward.

I have uploaded the contents of 7-8 gb of pdf files which includes pdf, docx, ppt etc in google drive. My concern is to list all the files that contain the term queried by user. For instance, if i want to search 'computer vision using google drive api' then the results should contain the list of files that contain the term 'computer vision' .

The above scenario is possible when i type something in google drive search box and below is the screen shot. [image]

When i type machine learning, i get list of files. How to retrieve the same results by programatically. I have read the documentation of google drive api and came across the syntac 'fulltext contains term' but then i don't know how to use it.

Comment: You have the full, very detailed tutorial about this topic in here: https://medium.com/@billydharmawan/google-drive-api-with-python-part-i-set-up-credentials-1f729cb0372b?   Make sure you read both part 1 and part 2.

Comment: @user5214530 Hey just one more concern, Over there we are not searching file names rather we are searching for content and in return i get the list of files that has that content. I just want to make sure we are on the same page. Because i have gone through many tutorials which retrieves the files

Comment: Yes, indeed we are, you have two alternatives: dependable on amount of your files on drive, you can fetch up the whole list, then do the filtering offline in standard python list, or filter in fetching process like described out here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files

Comment: Ok Thank you. I will look into it. Thanks once again

Comment: Hey @s326280 were you able to solve your issue with my answer? Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it in case it was useful to you. Otherwise, kindly describe the issue you are having,  so we may help you. Cheers

Comment: @carlesgg97 Apologies for the late response.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly said, an easy way to do this is to use the `q` parameter of the request, along with the `fullText contains X` operator. Below you can see an adaptation of the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) from the reference that uses this feature:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=1000, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)", q="fullText contains 'computer vision'").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Notice the `q` parameter upon calling the `service.files().list()` method.

#### Reference

- [Google Drive API - Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)
- [Python Drive API v3 reference - list()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#list)